Automatic screenshots from active apps
Is it technically possible on Android to have a service or an app running in the background taking screenshots of specific apps?
The idea is to take periodic screenshots of 2 or 3 specific apps only when they are active.

technically. i'm sure it's possible. since there are a lot of screenshot related apps on the store, you can check which app is active on the screen via UsageStatsManager
